# Partial Matching condition for Set attribute in DynamoDb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I saw that there is `CONTAINS` conditional operator to check for subsequence in scalar attributes and exact value matching in set attributes.

I wanted to perform a `subsequence check for each item inside a set attribute`. Does DynamoDb support this type of filtering?

I cannot seem to find anything like this in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not supported by DynamoDB. The [`contains`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html) function can be used to check the following conditions only:

> - a String that contains a particular substring.
> - a Set that contains a particular element within the set.

Furthermore, the definition of a Set does not require elements to be ordered, so it does not make sense to look for an ordered subset of the elements. If you require your data to be ordered, you must use a `List` attribute rather than a `Set` attribute.

**Edit:** I think I misunderstood your question. I initially thought you wanted to check if a set contains a certain ordered subset. Upon rereading your question, it seems like you are wanting to find out if any (or all) individual element(s) of a string set contains a given substring.

That is also not possible in DynamoDB, and since you can’t use a document path to access elements of a set, there’s no way to iterate through the elements, checking each one. You must perform this filtering in your application after getting the item back from DynamoDB.